# How to generate coverage report against particular commit ID of branch using diff-cover?

Tags: git, code-coverage, nose

I am using [diff-cover](https://github.com/Bachmann1234/diff-cover) for generating the test case coverage for my python code.
It is showing the diff-coverage report against the **master(latest commit) branch**, but I want to generate a test case coverage report against a **specific commit ID** from past on **master** branch itself. 
Currently I am using the following command to generate the coverage.

```
nosetests -sv tests/unit/common/web/test_page.py --with-coverage --cover-xml && diff-cover coverage.xml  --compare-branch=origin/master
```

**Does anyone have any suggestions for generating coverage report against particular commit ID on master branch using diff-cover ?**

Thank You.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this is too late, you can try:

```
diff-cover coverage.xml  --compare-branch=commit-id-here
```